# How to extend a text classification ML model to work with more than one language?

Tags: classification, natural-language

We are using (in production) an ML for text classification. We trained our model using some custom English text corpus. Currently, the model is working acceptable level of accuracy for our purpose. Now we want to extend it to handle French language as well. We are planning to investigate the following two approaches.

1. We have a French-language corpus. Therefore, we would like to train a new model for handling French text.
2. Use the same model trained with English corpus. But use a third-party language translation service (such as Google Translator) to translate French text to English before inputting it into the ML model.

So I would like to know your thoughts regarding these two approaches.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the many factors, the best thing is just to try out.

The translation probably only pays off when you have much more training data in English (and therefore a much better English model), the more French data you have, the lower the chance that it pays off. Also if the English data contains many culturally specific information (e.g., names of companies that only are in the U.S.), classifying the translation might work well either.

You also might be interested in using pre-trained [multilingual BERT](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P19-1493) or XML-R as input features. These models allow relatively easy transfer across langauges.